# Why does my toggle menu not show the effects of the :hover when working with media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have created a Toggle Nav where you click a button and the navbar pops out and everything works fine on desktop. When I make it responsive the Toggle Nav has no problems except it won't show the styles for the mobile-menu-itmes:hover class. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong....It has to be something with the CSS but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated it, thanks.

HTML

```
  <div class="menu-btn" id="toggle-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS

```
 .menu-btn {
  color: #4f6df5;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: none;


.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px;

  .mobile-menu-items {
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #242424;
    line-height: 4;
    display: block;
  }

  .mobile-menu-items:hover {
    background: #4f6df5;
    padding: .5rem;
    color: white;
    display: block;
   }
 }
}
```

Javascript

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('#toggle-btn');
const mobileMenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', clickedBtn);

function clickedBtn() {
//mobileMenu.classList.toggle("mobile-menu");

if (mobileMenu.style.display === 'none') {
    mobileMenu.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    mobileMenu.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Media Queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.menu-btn {
display: flex;



}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle so i can inspect it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lp6xnud/

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing closing curly bracket `}` in your media query, so it is not rendering these styles. I've added `background-color: red` to the media query to show you that it works.

```css
.menu-btn {
  color: #4f6df5;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.mobile-menu-items {
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #242424;
  line-height: 4;
  display: block;
}

.mobile-menu-items:hover {
  background: #4f6df5;
  padding: .5rem;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
    crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="menu-btn" id="toggle-btn">
  <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="mobile-menu-items" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: SCSS is a superset of CSS, so you can move the curly brackets for `.menu-btn` and `.mobile-menu` back to the end where you had them initially and it will work the exact same. SO code snippets do not support SCSS unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing curly braces for

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  }
}
```

so it is not showing hover effect ,
Check Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86tay3bv/)

Comment: It works in the fiddle but not on my local machine. I have a lot more code on my local machine so I just took the snippet that I was having issues with and posted it on here.